# Recognized printer not printing

Tags: ssh, debian, printer, printing, cups

I connected an HP 1000 J110 to my server which I access via ssh. Listing the USB ports it recognized it. Also I Pasted the PPD on the `/etc/cups/ppd/` folder... Is the ppd my pc uses to print when attached directly to the PC.

I Use `lpstat -p`

and it shows the printer there :

```
printer DESKJET-1000-J110 is idle.  enabled since Fri 22 Mar 2013 08:05:33 PM UTC
```

Then I use:

```
lp -d DESKJET-1000-J110 filetoprint.txt
```

request id is DESKJET-1000-J110-111 (1 file(s))

and it appears that the file is sent to the printer, and actually appear as completed, but it just doesn't print anything.

I Also tryed with HPLip And when trying to run `hp-setup` it says:

`error: No device selected/specified or that supports this functionality.`

I checked and this printer IS supported by hplip.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was not that complicated. I used the following code: (Erased before the existing printers using lpadmin -x PrinterName)

To view my URI:

```
lpinfo -v
```

I got this:

```
:~# lpinfo -v
network http
network socket
direct scsi
network lpd
network ipp
serial serial:/dev/ttyS0?baud=115200
direct usb://HP/Deskjet%201000%20J110%20series?serial=CN19S21RWB05D2
network beh
```

The `direct usb` part is the URI.

I had already a ppd file. So I copied it to `/etc/cups/ppd/`

Then I added the printer using:

```
:~# lpadmin -p Deskjet-1000-J110-series -E -v usb://HP/Deskjet%201000%20J110%20series?serial=CN19S21RWB05D2 -m /etc/cups/ppd/Deskjet-1000-J110-series.ppd
```

I got this error:
`lpadmin: Unable to copy PPD file!`

As it was already specified (the ppd file) .. I ran a test

`lp -d Deskjet-1000-J110-series fileToPrint`

And.. printed...